# Powershell Security Log Get-EventLog

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to write something up in powershell and completely new to powershell, I need help. What I'm trying to do is get information from the Security Log. Specifically, the last login for users over the last two weeks. The code that I have so far is getting login's for the event ID 4624 based on the last 100 events. This is also returning not just users but computers as well. How can I limit the results to just users over a period of two weeks? Is this even possible?

```
$eventList = @()
Get-EventLog "Security" -After $Date `
    | Where -FilterScript {$_.EventID -eq 4624 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[4].Length -gt 10} `
    | foreach-Object {
        $row = "" | Select UserName, LoginTime
        $row.UserName = $_.ReplacementStrings[5]
        $row.LoginTime = $_.TimeGenerated
        $eventList += $row
        }
$eventList
```

EDIT: Solved with code

```
$Date = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-14)
$Date.tostring("MM-dd-yyyy"), $env:Computername
$eventList = @()
Get-EventLog "Security" -After $Date `
    | Where -FilterScript {$_.EventID -eq 4624 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[4].Length -gt 10 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[5] -notlike "*$"} `
    | foreach-Object {
        $row = "" | Select UserName, LoginTime
        $row.UserName = $_.ReplacementStrings[5]
        $row.LoginTime = $_.TimeGenerated
        $eventList += $row
        }
$eventList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-before` and `-after` parameters to filter the log by date. Use `get-help get-eventlog -full` to see all the parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the -after section, with a little work, I got it running, check code above for completed script.

Answer (score 0):

The users's last logon is stored in Active Directory. Seems like it would be a lot easier to pull it from there than chewing through event logs.

Comment: That does not fill the needs of my script. I need the last 14 Days of logon events, not the last logon for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerShell to search the Active Directory:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-QADComputer -ComputerRole DomainController | foreach {
(Get-QADUser -Service $_.Name -SamAccountName username).LastLogon.Value
} | Measure-Latest
```

Comment: That does not fill the needs of my script. I need the last 14 Days of logon events for users, in general, not the last logon for each user.