# Filtering for newest security event records

Tags: powershell

I found some really nice code on how to display user logins from the past 14 days:
[Powershell Security Log Get-EventLog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025290/powershell-security-log-get-eventlog)

```
$Date = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-14)
$Date.tostring("MM-dd-yyyy"), $env:Computername
$eventList = @()
Get-EventLog "Security" -After $Date `
    | Where -FilterScript {$_.EventID -eq 4624 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[4].Length -gt 10 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[5] -notlike "*$"} `
    | foreach-Object {
        $row = "" | Select UserName, LoginTime
        $row.UserName = $_.ReplacementStrings[5]
        $row.LoginTime = $_.TimeGenerated
        $eventList += $row
      }
$eventList
```

But my question is, how do I modify this code so that it selects the two newest records?

I tried the following:

```
Get-EventLog "Security" -After $Date `
| Where -FilterScript {$_.EventID -eq 4624 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[4].Length -gt 10 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[5] -notlike "*$"} `
| {-Newest 2}
```

And I get the error: `Missing expression after unary operator '-'.`

What is a clean way to get the last two logins, i.e. current login and the last person who logged in before the current user?

EDIT:Issue solved, here is complete code

```
$Date = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-14)
$Date.tostring("MM-dd-yyyy"), $env:Computername
$eventList = @()
Get-EventLog "Security" -After $Date `
    | Where -FilterScript {$_.EventID -eq 4624 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[4].Length -gt 10 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[5] -notlike "*$"} `
    | Select-Object -First 2 `
    | foreach-Object {
        $row = "" | Select UserName, LoginTime
        $row.UserName = $_.ReplacementStrings[5]
        $row.LoginTime = $_.TimeGenerated
        $eventList += $row
        }
$eventList
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
| {-Newest 2}
```

Try this:

```
| Select-Object -first 2
```

Comment: But this filters ALL Security Event logs. I am looking to filter all security event logs where Event ID is 4624 to the first two.                                                              If I put -Newest first, it selects the first two Security Event logs, and if either of these two are Event ID of 4624, only then it displays. HELP!!!

Comment: Try Select-Object -first 2 instead

Comment: I cannot actually run the command because I dont have admin rights to my box :(